# What is the usecase of hash index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, rdbms

When to use hash index?

I know the theory of hashing: when search something by hash it's not comparable on `<` or `>`, it can only be equal or not. So in opposite to BTree cannot perform divide and conquer searching, rather try to be precise. But I cannot understand when it's useful?

Answer (score 6):

Hash indexes are faster than b-tree indexes -- at least in theory.  A b-tree index requires O(log n) effort to search.  A hash index is closer to constant time.

Given the improvement in performance, they are sometimes useful.  Often inequalities and sorting is not needed.

Comment: Yes, and what is the usecase? Which is the ideal case when use hash index?

Comment: The only theoretical use case is the speed gain that Gordon mentions. In practice, they are often not faster (zest it!) and hence pretty useless.

Comment: @Gordon, I completely agree, but provide a practical usecase please

Answer (score 4):

Hash indexes are useful for **equality queries**, i.e. when you look for an specific element in your table (for example, WHERE id=1). In this case hash indexes are theoretically faster.

On the other hand, if you need to search also for **ranges of elements** (for example, WHERE id>1 and id<10), then hash indexes are useless, you need btrees.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, btree indexes have a hard limit on the size of index entries at around 1/3 of the blocksize.  So if even 0.00001% of your table rows might have values longer than the limit, you have a problem.  Hash indexes avoid this limitation.

Comment: Great! Is this the only usecase when hashindex is useful?